# django rest framework using action decorator to add path to view financial statement in url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

I need the following URLs to work where ticker would stand for a stock ticker such as AAPL or AMZN, and is stands for income_statement.

`localhost:8000/stocks/`
`localhost:8000/stocks/<TICKER>/`
`localhost:8000/stocks/<TICKER>/is/`

in the views.py file below I am using a viewset which and router which automatically configures the first two urls above, and for the third url I am using the action decorator with `methods=['get']` and `url_path="is"` to achieve the `localhost:8000/stocks/<TICKER>/is/` path.

the third URL is configured, but I get a key error for `ticker` when entering the following url in the browser: `localhost:8000/stocks/AAPL/is/`

what am I doing wrong here, I believe the error is in the `views.py` `get_income_statement` function?

models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.ticker
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "stock"
        verbose_name_plural = "stocks"
        ordering = ["ticker"]

class IncomeStatement(models.Model):
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(
        Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="income_statements"
    )

    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    PERIODICITY_CHOICES = [("ANNUAL", "ANNUAL"), ("QUARTERLY", "QUARTERLY")]
    periodicity = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=PERIODICITY_CHOICES, default="annually"
    )
    net_income_continuous_operations = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=20, decimal_places=2
```

views.py

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    # lookup_field = "slug"

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"], url_path="is", url_name="is")
    def get_income_statement(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        income_statement = self.queryset.get(ticker=kwargs["ticker"]).select_related(
            "income_statements"
        )
        serializer = IncomeStatementSerializer(data=income_statement)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"stocks", views.StockViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: yes they both work correctly

Comment: the error is in the `get_income_statement` function of the views.py file

Comment: did that . . . resolved one error now I get the response `"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got RelatedManager."`

Comment: any fix to this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do in this action, maybe you want to return in `response` multiple `income_statements`? Because you can have more than one according to db sheme.

Comment: I want to return all the income statements for the specified stock year over year

Comment: So, you have to get `income_statements` as `self.get_object().income_statements` and than use your serializer as `IncomeStatementSerializer(data=income_statements, many=True)` P.S. Please clean old comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **`lookup_field = "ticker"`**

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # rest of your code
    lookup_field = "ticker"
```

### Update-1

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_field = "ticker"

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"], url_path="is", url_name="is")
    def get_income_statement(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        is_qs = IncomeStatement.objects.filter(ticker=self.get_object())
        serializer = IncomeStatementSerializer(is_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: that fixed the original problem, now I get the error `'Stock' object has no attribute 'select_related'`

Comment: `select_related` will only work with *QuerySet* not objects

Comment: Also, I don't see any reason that you need to call the `select_related()`

Comment: how would you do it ?

Comment: I used `model_to_dict` wrapper from django and now I have all the fields with the error `this field is required`

Comment: I think there is an error in `self.get_object` I returned the error `ot AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `net_income_continuous_operations` on serializer `IncomeStatementSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Stock` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Stock' object has no attribute 'net_income_continuous_operations'.`

I believe this is because I need to go one level deeper to the income_statements foreign key

Comment: That error indicates that you have defined one (or more fields) incorrectly.

Comment: is it possible since I want to return more than one income statement that its not serializing the list of income statements correctly, because the other two urls are working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220143/discussion-between-aran-freel-and-arakkal-abu).

Comment: can you explain to me how *args and **kwargs makes this snippet work . . . I don't get what it is providing to the function that makes it work

Comment: url parameters are passed to `kwargs`

Comment: so url parameters being ticker or is in the snippet above ?

Comment: how to make the urls in this case insensitve so whether the stock name is AAPL or aapl or Aapl in the URL it won't matter

Comment: Please ask a new question